# Laravel RoleMiddleware, class role not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I'm trying to add a simple middleware to check if a user matches a role.  I'm running into an issue when I use the middleware, I get an Exception:

> ReflectionException: class role does not exist

I do not attempt to call a class named role so I assume this is happening magically in Laravel somewhere.

My middleware:

```
class RoleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Run the request filter.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  $role
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->is($role)) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

In the users table, I have a role field and in the User model I have:

```
/**
 * Check if a user is a certain role
 *
 * @param $role
 * @return bool
 */
function is($role) {
    return ($this->role == $role);
}
```

The route group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'support', 'middleware' => ['role:admin', 'web']], function() {
        Route::get('threads', 'ThreadController@index');
});
```

In Http/Kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'role' => [
        RoleMiddleware::class,
    ],
];
```

Anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this ReflectionException?

Comment: Try `\App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class` and execut `dump-autoload` also, then tell us if it work.

Comment: The namespace is fine, it can reach the class and it throws an error about the missing argument if I just use middleware 'role' instead of 'role:admin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This came down to two problems:

1. `$middlewareGroups` may not allow for parameters. (Needs to be confirmed)  Dropping `RoleMiddleware` down to `$routeMiddleware` got rid of the exception.
2. Having 'web' after 'role:admin' resulted in a `null` `$request->user()`. So for future users, you may need to consider placement of your middleware and a check to see if `$request->user()` is null.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 25):

For Spatie/Laravel-Permissions to work properly we have to register the two route middleware (`role` and `permission`) in `app/Http/Kernel.php` as follows, along with the other two auth middleware:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
    'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
];
```

Comment: you can also now add
`'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,`
to `protected $routeMiddleware`

Comment: It is found [in the docs](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/middleware/).

Answer (score 5):

In `Http/Kernel.php`, you need to include the full path to `RoleMiddleware`. E.g.:

```
...
'role' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
],
...
```

Comment: It's imported with use so the full namespace is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'support', 'middleware' => ['role:admin', 'web']], function() {
    Route::get('threads', 'ThreadController@index');
});
```

to

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'support', 'middlewareGroups' => ['role:admin', 'web']], function() {
    Route::get('threads', 'ThreadController@index');
});
```

I'm a beginner in laravel i was facing this same problem and fixed by changing the name from middleware to "your-own-middelware-name".